# Salem and Perron polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $P(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ is a polynomial, let $d$ be its degree and let $P_{*}(t)$ denote its reciprocal polynomial, i.e. $P_{*}(t) := t^d\, P(1/t)$.

Let $Q_n(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ be a polynomial such that $(1-t)Q_n(t) = t^n P(t) - P_{*}(t)$ for some $n$ (I have $n=1,2$, at the moment). Let us suppose that $Q_n(t)$ is a Salem polynomial, i.e. the minimal polynomial for a [Salem number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_number).

My question is: Will $P(t)\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ always be the minimal polynomial for a [Perron number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_number) (or, shortly, a Perron polynomial)?

This question mainly comes out of my total ignorance in number theory, so I hope for your mercy if the answer is rather trivial.

Comment: What is known is that if $P(t)$ is not reciprocal ($\neq P_{*}(t)$), $P(0)\neq 0$ and $P(1)<0$, then provided $Q_n(t)$ is Salem for all $n$ large enough, $P(t)$ is a Pisot polynomial (the minimal polynomial for a Pisot number). Every Pisot number is a Perron number (also, every Salem number is a Perron number). However, here I've got $n$ bounded, in principle. Nevertheless, one can still suppose that $P(0)\neq 0$ and $P(1)<0$ in my case.

Comment: If you use the fact that $Q_n(t)$ is reciprocal, that may give some conditions on $P(t)$?

Comment: @SashaKolpakov: What is the relation of $n$ with the degree of the polynomial $Q_n(t)$?